# Breville smart oven and kashering

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul

I've seen [this oven](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B001L5TVGW/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A1LD8YQ23K3G6J) in a few places. The question is: whether it's an oven or a toaster oven in halacha. My family holds like the 'Aruch haShulchan (Yoreh De'ah 92:55) for regular ovens (that one may use the same oven for meat and milk, although not simultaneously) however we understand that toasters are keilim, and as such, cannot be used for both.

Other factors might include:

- size: toaster ovens are significantly larger now than they were, even a couple of decades ago
- function: today's toaster ovens are built to serve all of the functions of their larger counterparts
- ventilation: some newer toaster ovens use ventilation so as to avoid some of the problems which are discussed in halachic literature.

Would a smart oven (like the Breville in the link) be eligible for the 'Aruch haShulchan's understanding of an oven?

---

[CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi)

Comment: Is this the Aruch Hashulchan you are talking about? http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14242&st=&pgnum=434&hilite=

Comment: What is the Makom Gilui that the Aruch HaShulchan is talking about regarding  modern day ovens

Comment: Sorry I got caught up on the first line of the question